# How can I use multimedia keys for keyboard shortcuts in Linux?

Tags: shortcut, linux

I would like to be able to use keys like XF86AudioMute, XF86WWW, etc. for keyboard shortcuts in Blender. Apparently Blender has a few multimedia keys set up by default:
[image: Default media keys]

However, when I try to assign, for example, XF86AudioMute to an action in Blender, it sticks at "Press a key" just as if I had pressed nothing at all:
[image: Stuck at "Press a key"]

Why does it do this?



Some background information:

I have a Logitech G600, which is a mouse with a lot of buttons (22). I'd like to use these buttons in Blender, but I haven't figured out a particularly good way to do this.

The way the mouse presents the buttons to the computer is a little weird. As I have it set up, the left/right click, MMB, scroll up/down, and back/forward buttons are all normal mouse buttons, and Blender agrees with me; to set the back button on the mouse to undo in Blender, all I had to to was this:
[image: Back mouse button on mouse]

The rest of the mouse is actually a keyboard! Using Logitech's configuration software, I can make the other buttons type whatever letters I want, and that works fine in Blender. It's really no different from having two keyboards plugged into the same computer. However, I don't like this because it doesn't allow assigning an action only to the mouse.

It is possible to then [remap the keys](http://www.vxnick.com/blog/2014/10/binding-extra-mouse-buttons-on-linux/) on this mousy keyboard to [other random keys](http://hal.freedesktop.org/quirk/quirk-keymap-list.txt) that aren't on my (actual) keyboard. This works fine. The only problem is that, apart from those four in the screenshot above, I have found no keys that aren't already on my actual keyboard that Blender will recognize. How can I use these other keys with Blender?

Comment: Instead of assigning a single letter to a key, assign a key combination like Alt-Shift-H or Ctrl-Shift-F7 then set that in blender to do something.

Comment: @sambler Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't seem much better than what I have set up because I wouldn't be able to use additional modifier keys with the mouse buttons.